# Adding label to a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

How can one include a label on the x-axis of a pgfplot. Below is a MWE. What I desire is simply to have the label -0.7 indicated on the x axis.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
   width=60mm,
   height=40mm,
   axis lines=left,
   xlabel={$x$},
   every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
   ylabel={$f(x)$},
   every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
   enlargelimits={value=0.1,upper},
   scaled ticks=false, 
   minor x tick num=1,
   ytick=\empty,
   ]
\addplot[blue,domain=-3:3,samples=50]
{exp(-(x)^2 / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi))};

\addplot[blue,fill=blue!50!white, domain=-3:-0.7,samples=50]
{exp(-(x)^2 / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi))}\closedcycle;

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these

```
   extra x ticks={-0.7},
   extra x tick style={grid=major,
    tick label style={
    rotate=90,anchor=east}},
   extra x tick labels={$-0.7$},
```

to the axis options. If you don't want beautifications just

```
extra x ticks={-0.7},
extra x tick labels={$-0.7$},
```

would be enough.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   width=60mm,
   height=40mm,
   axis lines=left,
   xlabel={$x$},
   every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
   ylabel={$f(x)$},
   every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
   enlargelimits={value=0.1,upper},
   scaled ticks=false,
   minor x tick num=1,
   ytick=\empty,
   extra x ticks={-0.7},
   extra x tick style={grid=major,
    tick label style={
    rotate=90,anchor=east}},
   extra x tick labels={$-0.7$},
   ]
\addplot[blue,domain=-3:3,samples=50]
{exp(-(x)² / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi))};

\addplot[blue,fill=blue!50!white, domain=-3:-0.7,samples=50]
{exp(-(x)² / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi))}\closedcycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Without beautifications:

[image]

For beamer, you may draw them yourselves:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   width=60mm,
   height=40mm,
   axis lines=left,
   xlabel={$x$},
   every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
   ylabel={$f(x)$},
   every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
   enlargelimits={value=0.1,upper},
   scaled ticks=false,
   minor x tick num=1,
   ytick=\empty,clip=false
   ]
\addplot[blue,domain=-3:3,samples=50]
{exp(-(x)² / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi))};

\only<2->{\addplot[blue,fill=blue!50!white, domain=-3:-0.7,samples=50]
{exp(-(x)² / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi))}\closedcycle;}
\only<2->{\node[text=red,font=\small,rotate=90,overlay] at (axis cs:-0.7,-0.1) {$-0.7$};
}
\only<2->{\draw[thin,red,overlay] (axis cs: -0.7,-0.02) -- (axis cs: -0.7,0.4);
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So this goes in the `axis` environment. What if I want the label to appear on a second slide, can it not be attached to the addplot command?

Comment: Sorry about that! I didn't think the solution would be within the axes definitions. It appears that my MWE was too minimal!

Comment: @Geoff Its OK. :). Happens some times.

Answer (score 4):

How about a different labeling skill; use of `pin` that is not attached to the `addplot` command. Same for `article` class -- Remove `beamer` class and environment and `only<2->`

[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
   width=60mm,
   height=40mm,
   axis lines=left,
   xlabel={$x$},
   every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
   ylabel={$f(x)$},
   every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
   enlargelimits={value=0.1,upper},
   scaled ticks=false, 
   minor x tick num=1,
   ytick=\empty,
   ]
\addplot[blue,domain=-3:3,samples=50]
{exp(-(x)^2 / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi))};

\addplot[blue,fill=blue!50!white, domain=-3:-0.7,samples=50]
{exp(-(x)^2 / 2) / (sqrt(2*pi))} \closedcycle;

\only<2->{\node[pin={[pin distance=0.5cm,pin edge={<-,>=stealth'}]above right:$0.7$}] at (axis cs: -0.7,0){};}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```